# Get combinations where some items should appear more than others

Tags: combinations, combinatorics

I apologize if this is better suited to math.stackexchange.com, I just thought it's important that this is for programming.

Given an array of items `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, how can I get only the **combinations where certain elements appear a certain percentage of the time**?

i.e. only combinations where 'a' appears 70% of the time, 'c' appears 45% of the time, and 'd' appears 0% of the time.

I may not be asking the right question, but I'm struggling to word it correctly.

Right now, I have the below function that gets ALL combinations with no repetitions.

```js
function printCombos(items, r) {
  /**
   * This code is contributed by Devesh Agrawal
   * @param {*[]} items - input array
   * @param {number} slots - size of combination
   * @param {number} start - start index in items
   * @param {number} end - end index in items
   * @param {number} index - current index in items
   * @param {*[]} tmpData  - temporary array to store current combination
   */
  const getCombos = (items, slots, start, end, index, tmpData = []) => {
    if (index == slots) {
      // current combination ready to be recorded
      console.log(tmpData.join(' '))
      return;
    }

    // replace index with all possible elements. The condition 
    // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element 
    // at index will make a combination with remaining elements
    // at remaining positions 
    for (let i = start; i <= end && end - i + 1 >= slots - index; ++i) {
      tmpData[index] = items[i];
      getCombos(items, slots, i + 1, end, index + 1, tmpData);
    }
  }
  // first call
  getCombos(items, r, 0, items.length - 1, 0, []);
}
```

sample:

```js
const items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const slots = 3;

printCombos(items, slots);
```

Any resource, wikipedia article, etc. with more about this problem as it relates to percentages would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Do you mean a random generator which generates combinations with that distribution?

Comment: No I mean if I start with all combinations of size `r` for `n` items in a list, (following the formula `n! / r! * (n - r)!`) I want to not get all those combinations but only the ones where specific elements appear in `x` percent of the combinations. It doesn't have to be percentages, the real goal is to filter combinations based on each item having a integer priority value.

Comment: *"specific elements appear in x percent of the combinations"* is a property of a set of combinations, not a property of an individual combination. You cannot have a set of "the ones" that satisfy this property because it doesn't make sense for "one" combination to satisfy the property.